# Why does some words give segmentation fault? While others seem to work fine

Tags: c++, dictionary, trie

Making a dictionary using a trie in C++. Gives segmentation fault on some inputs.

Debugging helped me find that the problem was in the check function. Specifically after it exits the loop, at the check isword condition.

```
typedef struct node
{
    bool is_word;
    struct node *children[27];
} node;

node *createNode()
{
    // Void -> Node*
    // Create a pointer to a node(structure)
    // Allocate memory and store address in child pointer
    node *child = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    // Initialize each node in child to NULL
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        child->children[i] = NULL;
    }
    // Initialize the is_word variable
    child->is_word = false;
    // Return the pointer
    return child;
}

bool check(const char *word)
{
    int i = 0;

    // Create a pointer to the root of the trie
    node *ptr = root;

    // Iterate over each letter
    while (word[i] != '\0')
    {
        char c = tolower(word[i]);

        // Get the key for each letter
        int key = hash(c);

        // If the node at the key is null then word is misspelled
        if (!ptr)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr = ptr->children[key];
            i++;
        }
    }

    // Check if isword at the last letter is true
    if (ptr->is_word)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[image: error when input some words]

I expect the output to be FOUND or NOT FOUND, but actual output is a segmentation fault error.

Comment: Please post [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `node *ptr` how is node defined? Probably one of `ptr->children[key];` is uninitialized.

Comment: Please dont post code in comments, instead edit your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to check that `ptr` is not null, since it will be if you reach the end of the string and it's not a word in your trie.
You can also condense the code a bit.

```
bool check(const char *word)
{
    const node * ptr = root;
    for (int i = 0; ptr != nullptr && word[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        ptr = ptr->children[hash(tolower(word[i]))];
    }
    return ptr != nullptr && ptr->is_word;
}
```

Comment: That's really concise and works really great. Guess I have something to think about today. Curious though will '\0' be counted as true or false?

Comment: @PraveshPansari `'\0'` is zero. (I think my code bordered on obfuscated so I added explicit comparisons now.)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that ptr is returning `null`.

```
if ((ptr) && (ptr->is_word))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `if (something) return true; else return false;` --> `return something;`.